# Troubleshooting TinyMCE data retention issue

Tags: laravel, tinymce, save-as

I'm utilizing the TinyMCE editor in my application. It functions correctly in my local environment, storing data as expected. However, in the live environment on cPanel, the editor data is not being saved. Even upon form submission, the data is not retained.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'news_title' => 'required|string',
        'permalink' => 'required|string|unique:news,permalink',
        'short_description' => 'nullable',
        'long_description' => 'nullable',
        'featured_image' => 'nullable|string',
        'active' => 'nullable|integer',
    ]);
    
    if ($request->filled('categories')) {
        $validatedData['categories'] = implode(',', $request->input('categories', []));
    }

    $logged_in_user = Auth::user();
    $validatedData['created_by'] = $logged_in_user->id;
    $news = News::create($validatedData);

    $metaDescriptions = $request->only([
        '_seo_title',
        '_seo_tags',
        '_seo_description',
        '_alt',
        '_tagline',

    ]);

    $newsMeta = [];
    foreach ($metaDescriptions as $option => $value) {
        if ($value !== null) {
            $newsMeta[] = [
                'news_id' => $news->id,
                'option' => $option,
                'value' => $value,
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now(),
            ];
        }
    }

    # Insert news meta descriptions in bulk
    DB::table('news_meta')->insert($newsMeta);

    return redirect()->route('news-reports.create')->with(['success' => 'News Created Successfully!']);
}
```

Comment: Did yo ucheck if any errors in the log? What is the connection with cPanel and your problem? Are you sure not having any issue? are you working in production or local on remote server?